# Why Firebase ML Kit detect different contour values each time for same face

Tags: java, android, firebase-mlkit, google-mlkit

I am developing a face recognition app using firebase ML Kit. Although after doing many searches on google I come to know that Firebase ML kit does not provide functionality of Recognition.
But my question is here, that I detected contours of a face, saved them to a file, but when I again detected contours of same face they appeared different. Why this is so?? They must be same for same face??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are always going to be variances in the position of the face landmarks. For example, since the API provides X/Y coordinates for each point in the face, when the angle between the camera and the face is different the coordinates will change as well.

The API is really intended for applications like face masks and filters. Like you said the API does not support face recognition.

Comment: Thanks! What way I can use further to do face recognition?